# A function that separates points

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm trying to prove to prove the next proposition:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact metric spaces. Then any continuous function $f:X\times Y\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the uniform limit of functions with the form $$\phi(x,y)=f_{1}(x)g_{1}(y)+\cdots+f_{n}(x)g_{n}(y),$$ where $f_{i}\in C(X)$ and $g_{i}\in C(Y)$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}.$

If we prove that the class of such functions satisies the hypothesis of Stone-Weierstrass, we finish. So, I've proved that functions $\phi(x,y)$ as were defined satisfy every hypothesis of such theorem except that separates points.

I've been trying to prove this utilizing a function of the form $f(x)g(y),$ but I'm stuck on this. At the begin, I was thinking that one of them could be a constant function but I don't get any useful.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: Urysohn's lemma should help. As you say, functions of the form $f(x)g(y)$ will do to separate points.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan thanks for answer. I've been thinking about application of Urysohn's lemma but I feel lost. Could you give me a hand with this?

Comment: If $(x_1,y_1) \neq (x_2,y_2)$, then assume $x_1\neq x_2$. Use Urysohn's lemma to get a function $f\in C(X)$ such that $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$ and consider the function $f(x)1_Y(y)$, where $1_Y$ denotes the constant function $1$ on $Y$

Comment: You're right @PrahladVaidyanathan. Is enough to give two disjoint closed subsets of $X$ in which $f(x_{1})=1$ and $f(x_{2})=0.$ Many thanks for your help.