# Showing the closure of the sum .

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I was reading this [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2715124/a-function-that-separates-points?rq=1) and remember than in the book Real Analysis by Carother they ask you to prove the same but with $\phi(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$ However I can not prove the closure of the sum (I need it so I can use Stone-Weistrass.

The proposition is

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact metric spaces. Then any continuous function $f:X\times Y\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the uniform limit of functions with the form $$\phi(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$$ where $f\in C(X)$ and $g\in C(Y)$ .

And I want to prove:

$\phi(x,y)+\phi_1(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$ for some $f\in C(X)$ and $g\in C(Y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Let $X=Y=[0,1]$. Any function of the form $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ satisfies the equation $h(1,y)h(x,1)=h(x,y)h(1,1)$. Hence any function which is a uniform limit of such functions also satisfies this equation. But this means $h(x,y)%$ is itself of the form $f(x)g(y)$ (if $h(1,1) \neq 0$). By Stone -Weierstrass Theorem the closure under addition cannot be true.